# Looping through posts to find and create titles for tumblr photo posts

Tags: jquery, html, tumblr

I am creating a Tumblr theme and have run into a road block. Tumblr unfortunately does not allow for titles for the *Photo post type*. As such I have decided I want to take the `p:first-child` in each `aside` (where I am housing the caption / blog text) and replace the generic `hgroup h3 a` (the posts title) content with the `p:first-child` content i've selected; thus creating a title.

Hopefully this doesn't sound to convoluted. I am using jQuery for most animated elements on the page and would like to continue using jQuery to accomplish this task.

Here is the current code I am using:

```
$('section').each(function(index) {
         $('hgroup h3 a').append( $('aside p:first-child em') );
    });
```

the problem is that it's returning an array of all p:first-child elements resulting in 5 titles where only one should appear.

What I would like is to take each of the first-child elements that are found, and place each individual item in place of their parent title element.

Any help that could be provided would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `aside` is contained in it's own `section` you could do this:

```
$('section').each(function(index) {
     $('hgroup h3 a', this).append( $('aside p:first-child em', this) );
});
```

Comment: $(this).find('aside p:first-child em') should be more efficient

Comment: Thanks all. This worked perfectly. Definitely a nice trick to make up for the lack of a post-tag for Photo Posts